# How to enable HTML TextArea auto width resizing?

Tags: html, textarea, width, autoresize

Is it possible to have a HTML TextArea automatically resize its width with the browser window width (I mean dynamically)?

Comment: textarea { width: xxx%; } ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure. For example like this

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="flex">Test text</textarea>
```

**CSS**

```
#flex { width: 80% }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also achieve the following functionality by using bootstrap. Bootstrap uses grid layout and divides the whole screen in 12 grids, and as the screen window re sizes, different elements inside the body also gets shifted and re sized.You can download bootstrap library from this site: 
http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: it does not seems to be an answer, it may be a good suggestion, but not an answer.